# Writing a cloning function to generate unique names

Tags: php

I would like to create a clone function on the following array,

```
$usernames = array ( 'jack', 'amy', 'chris');
```

such that:

Cloning jack, would result in jack-1  (because jack-1 does not exist in usernames array yet). Once cloned, the usernames array should be updated to:

```
$usernames = array ( 'jack', 'amy', 'chris', 'jack-1');

Cloning jack, (again) would result in jack-2

Cloning jack-1, would result in jack-1-1
Cloning jack-1-1, would result in jack-1-1-1
Cloning jack-1-1 (again), would result in jack-1-1-2
Cloning jack-1-1-1 would result in jack-1-1-1-1
```

and so on and so forth..

I can work with in_array to do this, but looking for an efficient way to do this.

Thanks,

Comment: Is it guaranteed that `jack-1` doesn't exist when cloning `jack`?

Comment: In the first pass, yes. It's guaranteed that jack-1 does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Sajan's Logic, it works according to the requirement, if I modify the logic this way. Copying the original username and re-parsing the original array, does the trick.

```
$array = array('jack', 'sally');

function cloneFunction($value, $array)
{
    if (!in_array($value, $array))
    {
        $array[] = $value;
    }
    else
    {
        $i = 0;
        $j = 0;

        while(in_array($value, $array))
        {
            $i++;
            $value = $value . '-' . $i;

            $stagedValue = $value;
            while(in_array($value, $array))
            {
                $j++;
                $value = $stagedValue . '-' . $j;
            }
            $j = $i;
        }

        $array[] = $value;
    }

    return $array;
    // Do return $value if you just want the value.
}

print_r(cloneFunction('jack', $array));
```

Comment: Wonder if there's a more elegant way to do this, by cutting the code in half. :)

Comment: Awesome!  Glad you got it.

Comment: Thanks foe helping out :)

Answer (score 1):

I've tested this and it works.

First, we check if the the value already exists, if it doesn't, we just go ahead and add it.

If it does exist, we add the incrementing number with a dash to it.  We keep incrementing until we get to one that doesn't exist...then we add it.

```
<?php

$array = ['jack', 'sally'];

function cloneFunction($value, $array)
{
    if (!in_array($value, $array))
    {
        $array[] = $value;
    }
    else
    {
        $i = 0;

        while(in_array($value, $array))
        {
            $i++;
            $value = $value . '-' . $i;
        }

        $array[] = $value;
    }

    return $array;
    // Do return $value if you just want the value.
}

print_r(cloneFunction('jack', $array));
```

Comment: I edited this a minute or so after I posted to correct the logic.

Comment: hmm.. What if I wanted to return only the newly generated clone name instead of the array?

Comment: @Jake, then you can do `return $value` instead of `return $array`.

Comment: `clone` is some reserved word in PHP, I updated my answer with the final, tested code.

Comment: @Jake, thanks.  However, after a little more testing, I'm getting unexpected results for when `jack-1` already exists.  I'll take a further look in a few minutes.

Comment: Yeah, this needs a bit more work considering your requirements.  Post back if you get it.  However, it looks like you'll need to explode on '-' to properly increment the last number segment.  Else it will add a new segment when you don't want it to.  If you don't post, I'll come back and do it.

Comment: I see. okay. I will test it out some more. Thank you.